# Haskell - Function checks balancing within parenthesis

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function in Haskell that checks whether a string containing open and closed parenthesis is balanced. For every opened parenthesis there must be one closed and an empty string is considered balanced too.

```
Ex. (()) is balanced
(())) is not balanced.
()(()) is balanced.
()(())) is not balanced.
```

Thanks

Comment: That's right, **you** have to write such a function. We could help you, when you tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: In the process of investigating maximally-lazy solutions to this which don't involve writing your own recursion, I discovered semicomonads, as exposed by `Data.Functor.Extend` in the [semigroupoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids) package. So, thanks for the foray into interesting abstractions.

Answer (score 6):

In general keep a count. Increment if you see a ( and decrement if you see a ). If count becomes negative anywhere or is non zero at the end, you are doomed. Otherwise it is balanced.

Comment: this would make this `)(` a balanced expression, so you either have to keep track of opened/closed number of parens, or widen your definition of balanced.

Comment: No, when you see ) count becomes negative. Hence you are doomed. Count should never be negative, and should be zero at the end

Comment: okay I misread your answer - I thought you meant if count is negative at the end of the procedure.

Comment: I see a solution involving `fold`, `map` and a substitution function between your lines! ;-) +1

Comment: I haven't done Haskell. I know scheme. A single fold should do it :)

Comment: yes then you make the substitution function part of the folding function, in addition the compiler should optimize those two steps into one.

Comment: I'd go for a `foldM` in the `Maybe` or `Either e` monad, followed by `fmap (0 ==)`, `(Just 0 ==)` or `(Right 0 ==)`.

Comment: I really like using `scanl` to generate a running count of the nesting level, then making sure the running count never goes negative and ends at 0.

Comment: @Rhymoid Something like this? `isBalanced = maybe False (==0) . foldM (\n x -> let n' = n + fromC x in if n' < 0 then Nothing else Just n') 0 where fromC '(' = 1; fromC ')' = (-1)`

Comment: Yes, very much like that. But what about cases like `fromC 'A'`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tested function, it works fine:

```
module Main where
import Data.List

balanced s = length(removePairs s) == 0
 where removePairs []    = []
       removePairs (x:xs)
        | x == '('       = removePairs (removeLast xs 0)
        | (x:xs) == ")"  = "."
        | x == ')'       = xs
        | x == '.'       = (x:xs)
       removeLast []  _  = "."
       removeLast xs n
        | ')' `notElem` xs  = ")"
        | (xs!!n) == ')'    = (fst splitted)++(tail $ snd splitted)
        | length xs == n    = ")"
        | otherwise         = removeLast xs (n+1)
        where splitted      = splitAt n xs

main = print $ balanced "()()()(())" -- prints True
```

[codepad.org](http://codepad.org/mYKszfqd)